Conversion of multiple sdf files to pdbqt format
I have an sdf file of multiple ligands which is optimized previously with rdkit. Now I want to convert it to pdbqt format suitable for docking in one go - not manually and not with obabel. However the valencies should be satisfied correctly in the output when we add hydrogens.
How can I do this?

What about AutoDockTools? Also what languages are you familiar with? Python because I assume thats what is meant by RDKit? Are you looking for us to write the code for you (it's a fair amount of code) or just give advice? If you want us to write the code, generally we'd ask what code have your tried. Its not a hard task BTW, its just the way we answer things.

meaning you want us to suggest a library that does that ?? try this  https://oddt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rst/oddt.toolkits.extras.rdkit.html#oddt.toolkits.extras.rdkit.MolToPDBQTBlock  from https://sourceforge.net/p/rdkit/mailman/rdkit-discuss/thread/tencent_8D4F6996C36D1BC76C22068BDE1C6664ED06%40qq.com/#msg36978353

We wants advice...

use one of various tools sdf->pdb, then pdb->pdbqt with autodock tools.
